# Dividir una lista en dos

Tags: lista, prolog

Estoy teniendo problemas con el siguiente predicado:

```
partir(Todo, Parte1, Parte2)
```

que se verifica  si `Parte1` y `Parte2` son dos subsecuencias no vacías que concatenadas forman la secuencia Todo. Una posible traza sería

`[a,b,c,d]` se parte como `[a] [b,c,d]; [a,b] [c,d]; [a,b,c] [d].`

El orden tiene que prevalecer y no puede haber una lista vacía.

Lo estoy implementando como el predicado concatena, pero no logro evitar que en las soluciones por back tracking devuelva listas vacías.

```
partir([],[],[]).
partir(Ys,Ys,[]).
partir([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):-partir(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Comment: ¿ya intentaste metiéndole cortes? Ya sabes el símbolo de `!`

Comment: Aun no lo he probado, también porque no sabría muy bien donde meter el corte

Answer (score 0):

Para tu problema se me ocurrió primero declarar que no quieres listas vacías.

Esto lo hago usando la función `length`, y haciendo una aserción sobre el tamaño.

Adicionalmente ví que a `Ys` no le hacías nada , así que agregué otro predicado y para sortear un poco los casos en que `Ys` pudiera valer `[]`.

```
partir(Ys,Ys,[]).
partir([],[],[]).
partir([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):-
    partir(Xs,Ys,Zs)
    ,length([X|Xs],N)
    ,N>1
    .

partir([X|Xs],[X|Ys],Zs):-
    partir(Xs,Zs,Ys)
    ,length([X|Xs],N)
    ,N>1
    .
```

La salida será:

```
partir([1,2,3,4],X,Y).
```

> X = [1, 2, 3, 4],
> Y = [] ;

> X = [2, 3, 4],
> Y = [1] ;

> X = [3, 4],
> Y = [1, 2] ;

> X = [4],
> Y = [1, 2, 3] ;

> X = [3],
> Y = [1, 2, 4] ;

> X = [2],
> Y = [1, 3, 4] ;

> X = [2, 3],
> Y = [1, 4] ;

> X = [2, 4],
> Y = [1, 3] ;

> X = [1],
> Y = [2, 3, 4] ;

> X = [1, 2],
> Y = [3, 4] ;

> X = [1, 2, 3],
> Y = [4] ;

> X = [1, 2, 4],
> Y = [3] ;

> X = [1, 3, 4],
> Y = [2] ;

> X = [1, 4],
> Y = [2, 3] ;

> X = [1, 3],
> Y = [2, 4] ;

> false.

Answer (score 0):

Primero notar que el procedimiento que indicas no verifica que `Parte1` y `Parte2` concatenados forman `Todo`, por ejemplo con esta consulta (la segunda solución es incorrecta):

```
?- Todo=[a,b], partir(Todo, Parte1, Parte2).
Todo = Parte1, Parte1 = [a, b],
Parte2 = [] ;
Todo = [a, b],
Parte1 = [b],
Parte2 = [a] ;
Todo = Parte2, Parte2 = [a, b],
Parte1 = [] ;
Todo = Parte2, Parte2 = [a, b],
Parte1 = [].
```

Podemos escribir el procedimiento recursivo:

```
%partir(Todo, Parte1, Parte2)

partir([Y,Z|Zs], [Y], [Z|Zs]).   % paso base
partir([Y|Xs], [Y|Ys], Zs):-     % paso recursivo
  partir(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

dónde en el paso base declaramos que tanto `Parte1` como `Parte2` tienen un único elemento, y `Todo` es la concatenación de los mismos.

Luego en el paso recursivo vamos tomando 1 elemento de `Parte1` y lo colocamos al comienzo de la lista `Todo` y hacemos la llamada recursiva.

Ejemplo:

```
?- partir([a,b,c,d], Parte1, Parte2).
Parte1 = [a],
Parte2 = [b, c, d] ;
Parte1 = [a, b],
Parte2 = [c, d] ;
Parte1 = [a, b, c],
Parte2 = [d] ;
false.
```